# works as a command but not as a shell script. Why?

Tags: bash, shell, test

```
$ grep "apple" fruits.txt
apple
$ if [ $? == 0 ] ; then echo "A"; else echo "B"; fi
A
```

When I execute the above commands it works fine but when I run these commands as a shell script it throws error and prints B. Why is it so ?

```
$ sh temp.sh 
apple
temp.sh: 3: [: 0: unexpected operator
B
```

Comment: `sh` won't start `bash` but a more posix-compliant, simpler shell, probably `dash`. `[` will be a different builtin in bash and sh. In `sh` it will only work with a single `=`, not `==`.

Comment: (1) `==` is a bashism, use the more portable `=` instead.  (2) `=` is a string comparison, use `-eq` for numeric comparisons.  (3) You can do away with the `if` like this: `grep -q apple fruits.txt && echo A || echo B`.

Comment: call temp.sh with "bash temp.sh" and not "sh temp", or even better put bash in the shebang inside temp.sh and run it with ./temp.sh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `==` as the equality operator (which bash supports) but then running the script under `sh` which doesn't support it.  The solution is to replace:

```
if [ $? == 0 ] ; then echo "A"; else echo "B"; fi
```

With:

```
if [ $? = 0 ] ; then echo "A"; else echo "B"; fi
```

This will work under both `bash` and plain `sh`.

While it may make no difference in this particular case, `=` is a string comparison.  For testing for numeric equality, one should use `-eq`:

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then echo "A"; else echo "B"; fi
```

#### Example with `==`

Consider this script file:

```
$ cat script.sh
grep "apple" fruits.txt
if [ $? == 0 ] ; then echo "A"; else echo "B"; fi
```

It runs under bash:

```
$ bash script.sh
apple
A
```

It fails under dash (dash is the default sh on debian-like systems):

```
$ dash script.sh
apple
script.sh: 2: [: 0: unexpected operator
B
```

Except for the line number, you can see that this error message matches what you are seeing.

#### Simplifications

There is no need to access `$?` directly.  The code can be simplified to:

```
$ if grep "apple" fruits.txt; then echo "A"; else echo "B"; fi
apple
A
```

Or, using the logical-and, `&&`, and logical-or, `||`, operators:

```
grep "apple" fruits.txt && echo A || echo B
```

The above works because `echo A`, if executed, will always return success.

Comment: In this case, we can write `grep "apple" fruits.txt && echo A || echo B` -- that form may not be appropriate with commands more complex  than "echo"

Comment: @glennjackman Good idea.  I just added a section on simplifications and included that line.

Comment: @John1024 thanks for the detailed explanation. Now I figured it out that and changing the permission +x and running it as ./temp.sh runs fine..

Comment: `=` is a string comparison.  Use `-eq` for numeric comparisons (in `[` tests that is).  Not sure why so many people are still completely unaware of this point.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to have it run as a bash script, just like your local environment that you are comparing to

For the script to run under under bash, put this as the FIRST line of the program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```